# Help for formatting the ref{} of nested enumerate

Tags: enumitem

In the following MWE, the reference to a nested item of the list is denoted by `2. (ii)` but I would like `2. (b) (ii)`.

Could you help me to fix my code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate, 1]
{1., 
leftmargin  = 2em,
itemindent  = 0pt,
labelwidth  = 2em,
labelsep    = 0pt,
font        = \bfseries,
align       = left,
itemsep     = 1.5mm,
ref         = \mbox{\textup{\textbf{\arabic*.}}}}

\setlist[enumerate, 2]
{(a),
itemindent = 0pt,
labelwidth = 1.3em,
labelsep = 4pt,
align = left,
itemsep = 0.5mm,
ref=\mbox{\textup{\textbf{\theenumi{}}\hspace{1pt}(\alph*)}}}

\setlist[enumerate, 3]
{(i),
itemindent = 0pt,
labelwidth = 1.5em,
labelsep = 4pt,
align = left,
itemsep = 0.25mm,
ref=\mbox{\textup{\textbf{\theenumi{}}\hspace{1pt}(\roman*)}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item test

\item test
\begin{enumerate}
\item tast

\item tast
\begin{enumerate}
\item tost
\item \label{my_label}My label is here.
\item tost
\end{enumerate}

\item tast
\end{enumerate}

\item test
\end{enumerate}

In \ref{my_label}, we saw.

\end{document}
```

[image]

### EDIT

I tried replacing the last piece of code by

```
\setlist[enumerate, 3]
{(i),
itemindent = 0pt,
labelwidth = 1.5em,
labelsep = 4pt,
align = left,
itemsep = 0.25mm,
ref=\mbox{\textup{\textbf{\theenumii{}}\hspace{1pt}(\roman*)}}}
```

[image]

The result is better but the `(b)` is in bold font.

Is it possible to have it in normal font? From my reading of the documentation of `enumitem`, it seems to be impossible.

Comment: `ref=\mbox{\theenumii\hspace{1pt}(\roman*)}` should give you the desired result.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following example, I also tried to simplify the other `ref` options as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate, 1]
{1., 
leftmargin  = 2em,
itemindent  = 0pt,
labelwidth  = 2em,
labelsep    = 0pt,
font        = \bfseries,
align       = left,
itemsep     = 1.5mm,
ref         = \mbox{\textbf{\arabic*.}}}

\setlist[enumerate, 2]
{(a),
itemindent = 0pt,
labelwidth = 1.3em,
labelsep = 4pt,
align = left,
itemsep = 0.5mm,
ref=\mbox{\theenumi{}\hspace{1pt}(\alph*)}}

\setlist[enumerate, 3]
{(i),
itemindent = 0pt,
labelwidth = 1.5em,
labelsep = 4pt,
align = left,
itemsep = 0.25mm,
ref=\mbox{\theenumii\hspace{1pt}(\roman*)}}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item test \label{first-level}

\item test
\begin{enumerate}
\item tast \label{second-level}

\item tast
\begin{enumerate}
\item tost
\item \label{third-level}My label is here.
\item tost
\end{enumerate}

\item tast
\end{enumerate}

\item test
\end{enumerate}

In \ref{first-level}, we saw.

In \ref{second-level}, we saw.

In \ref{third-level}, we saw.



\end{document}
```

Comment: I have added a `\textup{}` because I don't like when the reference is in italics because the context is in italics.